# Why is this the condition for the while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

This function performs binary division. However, I'm confused with the condition of the loop "while len(b) ≤ len(a) and a".

**Why is there "and a" in the condition?**

Isn't "a" a list? So how come len(b) should be greater than that?

[image]

Thank you for your help! <3

Comment: Please post the actual code, not a screenshot of it

Comment: Please include any relevant information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), do not link or embed external images of source code or data. Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Comment: Show us *exactly* what you don't understand from when you traced the intermediate expressions in this code. "Explain this code block to me" is out of scope for Stack Overflow: deconstruct the compound expressions and tell us what you don't understand about one or two of those operations.

Comment: Think for a moment: under what condition does `a` evaluate to `False`?  Given that, under what condition would `len(b) <= len(a)` be `True`?  That tells you exactly the base case that `and a` covers.

Comment: I'm sorry! I was just wondering what purpose does "a" have here, so I thought a screenshot was enough. Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is evaluating whether "a" is true or false. It is really evaluating the size or length of "a".  If "a" has any values then it will evaluate to true.  If "a" is empty it will evaluate to 0 or false.

The length of "a" and "b" could both be 0 and if "and a" was not included and "a" was empty then the "if a[0]" expression would cause an out of bounds exception.

Basically, ignore the while loop if "a" is empty.  It seems like it would be simpler to check for the status of "a" first.

Answer (score 1):

In python, empty lists has boolean value 0, so `and a` might check that list `a` isn't empty

Answer (score 1):

## How to read `while` loops

I think there's a misconception of how you read `while` loop.

As you have in your code:

```
while len(b) <= len(a) and a:
```

It means it **has 2 conditions**, `len(b) <= len(a)` and `a`. So don't read as `len(b) <= len(a) and a` !

In other words **it doesn't mean** `len(b)` has to be smaller than `len(a)` and `a`.

---

### Let's read `a`

The second condtion (`a`) may looks weird, because in real life that doesn't make any sense.

> But programming language **is different** than real life sentence

Say have these codes:

**Code 1**

```
a = []
print(bool(a))
```

**Code 2**

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 3]
print(bool(a))
```

---

- **Code 1** will prints out `False`
- **Code 2** will prints out `True`

The reason for that is, in python **when a variable has value in it, it equals `True`**.

---

## Conclusion

Back to this code:

```
while len(b) <= len(a) and a:
```

That code also means keep going **`while`** `len(b) <= len(a)` and `a == True`.

So the `while` loop there means, `len(b)` **has to be** smaller than `len(a)` **AND** `a` has to be `True` (must have value).

---

### I really hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

> Why is there "and a" in the condition?

The while loop is checking 2 conditions, first it checks that the length of the `b` list is less then or equal to the length of the `a` list. Then an `and` statement is used to tell the interpreter you would like to check a second condition, in this case the contents of `a`. `and` is simply telling the interpreter to check multiple conditions.